# ionic ion-radio change the color when it's selected

Tags: ionic-framework, radio-button

How to change the color of radio button in Ionic when the users selected the radio button.
I wanna change the whole list or area, not the radio-icons.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example?